# Can't run firefox in headless mode

Tags: selenium, phpunit, headless-browser

According to documentation to start selenium server in headless mode I am supposed to launch the server with the xvfb-run wrapper under a specific Firefox profile. 
This can be done with following command : 

`DISPLAY=:1 xvfb-run java -jar selenium-server.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate /home/ronline/.mozilla/firefox/aqiycn5z.selenium`

Once I get system acknowledgement that selenium server is up and running
I call my phpunit script to execute a set of basic tests

`phpunit --log-tap test.log test.php`

but the excution freeze with a selenium server output about launching firefox 

`17:50:33.300 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
17:50:36.376 INFO - Launching Firefox...`

Firefox headless mode is supposed to run out of the box. 
Are there any additional drivers to be installed in the order to get this work?

Installation details:

`firefox --version Mozilla Firefox 38.0
PHPUnit 4.6.6
Ubuntu LTS 12.04`

The content of the test.php :

```
<?php
class EditUser extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
  protected function setUp()
  {
    $this->setBrowser("*firefox /usr/lib/firefox/firefox");
    $this->setBrowserUrl("http://www.google.com");
  }

  public function testMyTestCase()
  {
    $this->open("/");
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the Firefox 38.0 is still not supported by the selenium server. The solution is to install the Firefox 34.0 and point to the selenium server to its binary executable:

```
$this->setBrowser("*firefox /opt/firefox/firefox-34/firefox-bin");
```

Another option is to remove the setBrowser method from the unit test file and injecting the bellow xml snippet to the phpunit xml configuration file.

```
<selenium>
<browsername="Firefox"
browser="*firefox /opt/firefox/firefox-34/firefox-bin" 
    host="localhost" 
    port="4444"
    timeout="30000"/>
</selenium>
```